# Moto Z Play Won't boot after SuperSU install

Tags: rooting, adb, recovery-mode, factory-reset

My Moto Z Play boot process won't finish. I can get to the Fastboot screen by powering off and pressing Power+Volume Down, but can't boot into Recovery Mode or Factory Mode. Both start the normal boot cycle which doesn't seem to finish. Powering off the device just restarts it. Even holding the power button for 10+ seconds doesn't power off, it just restarts the boot process.

Steps:

1. I unlocked the boot loader per Motorola instructions
2. Installed ADB and Fastboot to my laptop
3. Installed TWRP
4. Installed SuperSU. SuperSU kept going back to "Root Undetected" so I attempted a wipe to start fresh

Now the device attempts to boot as if wiped, which I can tell because when the Z Play boots after a factory reset it plays a "Hello Moto" clip. But the boot process doesn't finish. The same happens if I try to boot to recovery mode. Also, ADB doesn't show the device as attached anymore.

Is there any way of recovering the device, or am I buying a new one?

EDIT:
Android version 7.0.1

[Following the guide here](http://www.stechguide.com/root-and-install-twrp-recovery-on-moto-z-play/)

TWRP Download from [Here](https://androidfilehost.com/?w=files&flid=126925)

SuperSU download from [Here](https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=529152257862688685)

Comment: Sorry- details added. Not sure about SuperSU systemless vs. normal, so I hope linking to the instructions I used helps

Comment: Thanks for details. Some version of SU (forget which) didn't go well work a lot of devices. Suggest you browse your device forums on XDA and see which is the best version and also see the rooting procedures in detail. Some devices especially Moto ones required special treatment by way of entering commands in TWRP . Upvoted for the effort taken in writing a detailed question

Comment: Appreciated. I've spent the morning going through XDA forums, but every answer I've found uses ADB or requires booting into TWRP and I can't do either anymore.

Comment: I am not familiar with your device and hopefully someone will pitch in